# How to change a variable value in jQuery if an item's siblings do not have a class (within mixitup plugin)?

Tags: jquery, variables

I know that you can specify if an item does not have a class by using this:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("test")) {
```

This is great, but I can't work out where in my code to use it.  I am using the mixitup jQuery plug for filtering, and there's a few if conditions throughout.  What I want to say is, if none of the siblings of `$t('[data-filter="all"]` have the class 'active', then apply the class active to `$t` and set the variable filterString to 'all'.

The effect, I hope, will be that if you remove all your filters, it will set it back to the default 'All' filter.  See below:

```
// INSTANTIATE MIXITUP

$('#equipment-grid').mixitup({
    //layoutMode: 'list', // Start in list mode (display: block) by default
    //listClass: 'list', // Container class for when in list mode
    //gridClass: 'grid', // Container class for when in grid mode
    effects: ['fade', 'blur'], // List of effects 
    //listEffects: ['fade','rotateX'] // List of effects ONLY for list mode
});

// HANDLE MULTI-DIMENSIONAL CHECKBOX FILTERING

/*  
 *  We can't used the default multiFilter because it
 *   behaves differently to what is required here.
 */

var $filters = $('#filters').find('li');
var filterString = 'all';

// Bind checkbox click handlers:

$filters.on('click', function () {
    var $t = $(this),
        filter = $t.attr('data-filter');

    if (filter == 'all') {
        // If "all"
        if (!$t.hasClass('active')) {
            // if unchecked, check "all" and uncheck all other active filters
            $t.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            // Replace entire string with "all"
            filterString = 'all';
        }
    } else {
        // Else, uncheck "all"
        $t.siblings('[data-filter="all"]').removeClass('active');
        // Remove "all" from string
        filterString = filterString.replace('all', '');
        if (!$t.hasClass('active')) {
            // Check checkbox
            $t.addClass('active');
            // Append filter to string
            filterString = filterString == '' ? filter : filterString + ' ' + filter;
        } else {
            // Uncheck
            $t.removeClass('active');
            // Remove filter and preceeding space from string with RegEx
            var re = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + filter);
            filterString = filterString.replace(re, '');
        };
    };

    /*
     *  We then send these strings to MixItUp using the filter method. We can send as
     *  many dimensions to MixitUp as we need using an array as the second argument
     *  of the "filter" method. Each dimension must be a space seperated string.
     */

    $('#equipment-grid').mixitup('filter', [filterString])
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
// if we're left with nothing selected, check 'All' again
if ($filters.filter('.active').size() == 0) {
    $filters.filter('[data-filter="all"]').addClass('active');
    filterString = 'all';
}
```

This would go in your code right after you've finished all your other checkbox processing, but before you call `mixitup()`. So right above your comment block.

Basically, once we finish all our processing, we look at all the elements in `$filters`, and if there's none that match `.active`, then we find the **all** filter, and add the active class to that. Note that at this point, we don't care which one was just clicked.. we don't reference `$t` here at all.

Comment: That looks good,thanks @jcsanyi.  But, where would that go in my script?  After the previous if/else statement?

Comment: Updated with a new answer, and where it goes.